# Cucumber grails not working with spring security

Tags: java, grails, spring-security, cucumber

I'm trying to use Cucumber 0.10.0 and Geb 0.9.2 on Grails 2.1.5 and Java 1.7 to test a login authentication with Spring Security. Although the login authentication with spring security is working on the app, at the scenario that tests a valid user (on the database) it is not. This code may explain better what's going on:

```
Scenario: Log in as a generator
    Given I am at the HomePage
    When I go to the login page
    And Enter the username "ru"
    And The password "pass" at the correct fields
    Then I log in as a generator

Given(~'^I am at the HomePage$'){->
    to HomePage
    at HomePage
}

When(~'^I go to the login page$'){ ->
    page.clickLogIn()
    at LoginAuthenticationPage
}

And(~'^Enter the username "([^"]*)"$'){ String username ->
    page.fillUsername(username)
}

And(~'^The password "([^"]*)" at the correct fields$'){ String password ->
    page.fillPassword(password)
}

Then(~'^I log in as a generator$'){->
    page.logInButtonClick()
    at GeneratorDashboardPage
    page.logOff()
}
```

At the "Then" step, when the method

```
page.logInButtonClick()
```

is called and the login authentication tries to be confirmed this error occurs:

```
Error |
2015-11-09 15:44:22,900 [http-bio-8070-exec-8] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /ResS/dashboard
Cannot invoke method getAuthorities() on null object. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Cannot invoke method getAuthorities() on null object
```

This method `getAuthorities()` is from a controller class that decides where this type of user is redirected when logged in:

```
class DashboardController {

    def springSecurityService;

    def index() {
         User user = (User)springSecurityService.currentUser;
            if(user.getAuthorities().contains(Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_GENERATOR')))
                redirect(controller: "generatorDashboard", action: "index")
            if(user.getAuthorities().contains(Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_COLLECTOR')))
                redirect(controller: "collectorDashboard", action: "index")
    }

}
```

I noticed that the

```
def springSecurityService
```

dependency is not being injected, therefore the object

```
User user = (User)springSecurityService.currentUser;
```

is null. Anyone knows why the dependency is not being injected? I thought maybe this Cucumber version does not support this type of testing.

Comment: It is being injected otherwise you would be getting the `NullPointerException` on `springSecurityService.currentUser` instead of `user.getAuthorities()`.

Comment: But the NullPointerException is on the user like it's said here: "Message: Cannot invoke method getAuthorities() on null object"

Comment: what is null the object, therefore it's the springSecurityService.currentUser